# Vk_api has no attribute 'longpoll'

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Появилась проблема с кодом, всё никак не могу её решить,при запуске бота появляется это:

> ```
> long_poll = vk_api.longpoll.VkLongPoll(vk_session)
> AttributeError: module 'vk_api' has no attribute 'longpoll'
> ```

Вроде бы и понятно что проблема с этим фрагментом кода, но при изменении его ничего не меняется, вот код бота:

```
import vk_api
import requests

# ID группы ВК

GROUP_ID = АЙДИ_ВКОНТАКТЕ

# Токен доступа к API ВК
VK_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'токен'

# URL вебхука Discord
DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL = 'вебхук'

# Авторизуемся в ВК
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=VK_ACCESS_TOKEN)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

# Получаем список участников группы
members = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id=GROUP_ID)['items']

# Устанавливаем соединение с сервером ВК через Long Poll API
long_poll = vk_api.longpoll.VkLongPoll(vk_session)

# Бесконечный цикл ожидания событий
for event in long_poll.listen():
    # Если это событие нового поста в группе
    if event.type == vk_api.longpoll.VkEventType.WALL_POST_NEW:
        # Получаем информацию о посте
        post = vk.wall.getById(posts=f'{GROUP_ID}_{event.object.id}')[0]

        # Получаем информацию об авторе поста
        user_id = post['from_id']
        user = vk.users.get(user_ids=user_id)[0]

        # Формируем сообщение, которое будем отправлять в Discord
        message = f'Новый пост in {post["owner_id"]} by {user["first_name"]} {user["last_name"]}: {post["text"]}'
        requests.post(DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL, json={'content': message})
```

Comment: from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll
и замените long_poll = vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, GROUP_ID)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать атрибут "longpoll" модуля "vk_api", но в действительности этого атрибута там нет.

Вероятно, вам нужно импортировать класс VkLongPoll из модуля vk_api.longpoll, чтобы использовать его в вашем коде.

Попробуйте добавить следующую строку перед строкой, где вы создаете объект VkLongPoll:
`from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType`

И замените эту строку:

`long_poll = vk_api.longpoll.VkLongPoll(vk_session)`

На эту:

`long_poll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)`